# Find the magnitude of the force required to keep a 4000 lb car from rolling down a hill with 5 degree slope.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the magnitude of the force required to keep a $4000$ lb car from rolling down a hill with $5^0$ slope using vectors and projections.

I tried to use one vector $(4000 \cos 5^0, 4000 \sin 5^0)$, but I don't know the other vector to use.

Comment: One vector is the downward gravitational force and the unit vector of the slope is $(\cos 5^0, \sin 5^0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force due to gravity is vertically downward. represent it as

$F = -4000j$

To keep the car from rolling down, you need to project this force onto unit vector v in the direction of the hill -

v $= \cos 5^0 \, i + \sin 5^0 \, j \,$ (v is a unit vector)

Projection of force $F$ on onto unit vector v -

$w = \frac{F \cdot.v}{||v||^2} v$

Dot product of $F$ and $v$ is $-4000 \sin 5^0$ and $||v||^2 = 1 \,$ being the unit vector.

So, $w = - 4000 \sin 5^0 (\cos 5^0 \, i + \sin 5^0 \, j) \,$

Magnitude of the force therefore is simply $\, 4000 \sin 5^0$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right angled triangle and then label its sides A,B,C.
Then try finding relations between A,B,C using sines and cosines. This should help you visualize all such problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Draw a free body diagram and consider the forces at work on the object.

You've got an object being acted upon by 4000 lb force downwards, and a normal force up and to the right at a five degree angle from the vertical, and a value equal to the amount of gravitational force acting in the line perpendicular to the slope. For simplicity, we can then translate this by rotating it five degrees, so that the normal force acts vertically and the gravitational force is sloped five degrees to the right.

You can calculate this value by drawing a right triangle with the gravitational force on the hypotenuse and the x and y components of the force on the other two sides of the triangle. The vertical component is equal to the normal force, in the opposite direction, while the horizontal component is equal to the amount of force pulling the car down the slope. We can then use trigonometry to calculate this; sin = opposite over hypotenuse, and we want to work out the opposite side given the values of the hypotenuse and angle, so sin (5 degrees) = opposite/4000, and therefore the horizontal value of the force is 4000 sin (5 degrees).

We can therefore state that the force needed to stop it sliding down the cliff, in the original coordinate scheme, is 4000 sin (5 degrees) pounds-force up and to the left at a 5 degree angle.

If we need to work out the vector components for this vector in the original coordinate scheme, we can do the same thing again, with 4000 sin (5) degrees on the hypotenuse of a right triangle with an angle of 5 degrees, the horizontal component on the adjacent side and the vertical component on the opposite side. We can then work out that the horizontal component of the force is cos (5 degrees) = adjacent/4000 sin (5 degrees) and therefore equal to 4000 sin (5 degrees) * cos (5 degrees), while the vertical force is similarly 4000 sin (5 degrees) * sin (5 degrees).